# How to make Texture2D as image.png in C#

Tags: encode, texture2d

Here I tried to save the texture as a picture. But the program does not respond. And the picture does not appear. Why?

```
void Start () {
    SceneSettings = GameObject.Find("Scene Settings");
    boardScript = SceneSettings.GetComponent<BoardScript>();
}

public void DownloadOptionsFunction()
{
    FullImageTexture = new Texture2D(pixelsQuality * boardScript.width, pixelsQuality * boardScript.height);

    for (int y = 0; y < boardScript.height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < boardScript.width; x++)
        {
            Color color = boardScript.PixelElement[boardScript.width * y + x].GetComponent<Image>().color;
            for (int y2 = y * pixelsQuality; y2 < pixelsQuality * (y + 1); y2++)
            {
                for (int x2 = x * pixelsQuality; x2 < pixelsQuality * (x + 1); x2++)
                {
                    FullImageTexture.SetPixel(x2, y2, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FullImageTexture.Apply();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/" + boardScript.name, FullImageTexture.EncodeToPNG());
}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: I fixed the tags
I want to know how to save the texture as a picture in the gallery